# Content loaded through JS not loading in IE9 unless the console is open

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

Ok, so this is something I have never seen before. I have a site that is loading in content using javascript. It works in Chrome, Opera, Firefox, Safari and IE 10. The only place that it does not work is IE9. This would be fine except that it will load in IE9 if your console is open or if you open your console while on the page.

Does anyone have any thoughts about this issue? I have included my code bellow.

```
if($("#event-container").doesExist()){
    var prop = jQuery('#prop').val();
    var num = jQuery('#num').val();
    var current = jQuery('#current').val();
    var url = "/example/eventsPull?prop="+prop+"&num="+num+"&current="+current;

    console.log(url);
    $.get("https://example.com" + url, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        if (data.length > 0) {
            $("#event-container").append(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I had a similar problem once. My problem was that I assumed an AJAX call response to be completed, which most of the times it was. Opening the console  may slow some processes down so that an ajax call (and its callback) are complete when you get to this point in the code.
I would suggest you check for that. Can't see an error in this code. Only question, what happens if $("#event-container").doesExist() returns false?

Comment: @PeterFischaleck Thanks for the response. I have added in some more error checking code so hopefully that will help narrow it down. If $("#event-container").doesExist() returns false then it simply doesn't do anything. It is just checking for that section of code to be there before looking for the rest.

Comment: `console` is not defined in IE9, if the console isn't opened. Just remove loggings, or polyfill the `console` object.

Comment: @Teemu I tried removing the console.log and it removed the errors, but didn't help the content to load.